# Core Bluetooth read Data

Tags: ios, bluetooth

Hi guys please help me with this.I have an HM-11 connected to my arduino and I want to read the state of an LED via bluetooth on my iPhone. I am able to control a servo via a custom app. I don't know how to go about reading data from the arduino.

```
func read()
{
self.peripheral.readValueForCharacteristic(char)
    print(char.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` to get the result of `readValueForCharacteristic`:

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {
    // TODO: check error here.

    // if you're expecting a string
    let strValue = NSString(data:characteristic.value!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    // do something with strValue
}
```